# Always show ribbon commands with "compressed" items

Tags: microsoft-office, ribbon

I have a new Office 365 ProPlus installation. By default, ribbon commands are hidden and when I expand them, the ribbon looks *"normal"*:

[image: desired ribbon look]

However, I also want the ribbon to be always visible, but when I select the *"Show Tabs and Commands"* ribbon option, the ribbon looks very ugly with more inter-command spacing:

[image: ribbon look]

How can I get the "normal"/"compressed" ribbon look with the *always-show-ribbon* option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pinning the Ribbon permanently

If your ribbon looks like this:

[image]

You can pin the ribbon by expanding and clicking "Pin":

[image]

---

## Changing from Touch Mode to Mouse Mode

If your ribbon looks expanded, this is because it is in **Touch** mode:

[image]

It is possible if you have a tablet computer, Office automatically switched to tablet mode when you disconnected your keyboard. Regardless, you can change it to **Mouse** mode by clicking the hand icon in the upper left corner of the Quick Access Toolbar and selecting Mouse:

[image]

If you don't see that, click the arrow on the toolbar and add that to the Menu. Once you've made the change, you can again remove it from your Quick Access menu if you don't want it there.

[image]